# How to get values of $a$ from $3 > \log_{5/4}a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I cannot come up with the solution to how to get $a$ from $$3 > \log_{5/4}a.$$

If it would be equality, we would get $(5/4)^3 = a$

But what should I do for inequality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the basis is bigger than one thus the logarithm is increasing:

$$\log_{\frac54}a<3=\log_{\frac54}\frac{125}{64}\implies a<\frac{125}{64}$$

Comment: Can you explain this in more details.. I did not understand how you got the equality

Comment: @PTNPNX I just wrote your inequality the wrong direction. All the rest, and the reason, remains: $$x>1\implies \log_x m<\log_xn\implies m<n$$

Answer (score 0):

Careful! While Timbuc is correct, notice that he switched the sign on the inequality. So for your original inequality, "a" needs to be less than 125/64.

I recommend proving this to yourself by plugging in an "a" that is larger than 125/64 ~ 2.0 (for example 625/256 ~ 2.4) and see if the inequality holds true. Then try a value of "a" that is less than 125/64 (such as 25/16 ~ 1.6) and see what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Following the other two responses, $0<a<1.953125$ satisfies the given equation.